# Jest Test fails even when the function passes

Tags: javascript, jestjs

The jest case fails even when the function when executes returns true.
In the test case I am asserting toBeTruthy as the function returns true for the same argument.

In the console logs I could see the function returns true, but when I assert in `expect` it returns false.

The sample test case is:-

```
const { regexString } = require("./samplemethods");

test("regexString should return true when", () => {
  const str = "He@l";
  expect(regexString(str)).toBeTruthy();
});

test("regexString should return true with invalid strings", () => {
  expect(regexString("He@l")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The sample function to test is:-

```
const NAME_PATTERN = /[!$%@^&*()+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/gim;

export function regexString(param) {
  console.log(param, NAME_PATTERN.test(param));
  return NAME_PATTERN.test(param);
}
```

Here is the link:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-playground-forked-e9t5q?file=/src/samplemethods.test.js

Comment: Take the `console.log` out - or at least rewrite it so that the `test` method is only called once. This method "keeps state", so calling it twice in a row can easily give different results.

Comment: Thank-you foe the details.  It worked after removing the console.log. As per the MDN when we use the g flag then whenever there is a match the index gets updated.  when I removed the g flag it worked as well.  Here is the updated link. https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-playground-forked-e9t5q?file=/src/samplemethods.js